# Need help understanding ios http auth for app

Tags: ios, authentication

I need an idiots guide explanation to understand generally how do you authenticate users in your ios app when you have a web based backend? I use tornado and django and understand how to use get/post/delete/update using restkit but theoretically i don't understand authentication requests.

P.S. I have found a good tutorial using restkit for authentication which helped here:
http://benoitc.github.com/restkit/authentication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done in multiple ways ill explain the easiest, first lets setup our enviroment, we do have:

- `www.yourSite.com/login.php`: this will take user="name" and passowrd="password", and it will echo back a session ID.
- `www.yourSite.com/isloggedin`.php: to check if user is logged in
- `www.yoursite.com/logout.php`: to logout from your session

First you would call login.php sending the user name and the password (`login.php?user=someuser&passowd=pass`) this call will echo back a session ID (that will be kept alive for you at the server side)

Then later on you could call `isloggedin.php?session=here_set_the_session_returned_earlier`, if you didnt log out this will return yes for example

Later if you want to logout you could call `www.yoursite.com/logout.php?session=same_session`, that will destroy the session saved in the login function

There are alot of other ways to implement this, but in my opinion this is the easiest way

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! How would this work with something like facebook login on ios, theoretically?

Comment: hmmm well facebook has its own login logout mechanism, it stores the date in some places, you could download facebook SDK for iOS it got everyhing you need

Comment: i am assuming Facebook sends me something on the device but what would i send back to my server?

Comment: why would you want to send it back to your server?

Comment: to get info that is relative to the user such as profile data, comments. I am assuming that the user has registered on my website before and is now accessing the app version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12842/discussion-between-rubygladiator-and-omar-abdelhafith)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cookie.

The web server side can respond some cookies when receiving the request that contains username and password information, then the next time app will send request with the cookies the web server has responded.

You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), it can handle cookie automatically.
Hope this can help you. :)

Comment: i was thinking that, i usually set secure cookie on website, it seems like i just send that secure cookie back to my app.